# C++ difference between a reference and a pass-by-reference argument

Tags: c++, reference, arguments

My question relates to the following member function of Bifstream which inherits from ifstream.
Read expects a char pointer.  I give it (char*)&target.  target is a reference so what I've given it is a reference to a reference to an int.  Why does this work?

```
bool cBifstream::ReadInt( int& target ){
    if( !this->is_open() ){
        return false;
    }
    this->read( (char*)&target, sizeof(int) );
}
```

Here is a snippet from other working code that I use.

```
int size;
is.read((char*)&size, sizeof(int));
```

The syntax is the same but this time the variable is an int and not a reference to an int.

Target declaration:

```
cBifstream a("test2");
int b;
a.ReadInt(b);
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the replies.
I still do not understand one thing.

```
this->read( (char*)target, sizeof(int) );  (all i did here was remove the ampersand)
```

This change causes my program to crash.  However target is a reference to an int so the above should work because

```
int size;
is.read((char*)&size, sizeof(int));
```

works.

Comment: Reference and pointer are two different things. Don't use these words interchangeably, because you will confuse yourself. Even if references are implemented with pointers in most (all?) compilers, they are not pointers.

Comment: what do you mean by `target is a reference so what I've given it is a reference to a reference to an int`. When a reference is passed (not pointer) inside the function it automatically dereferences itself. So the line `this->read( (char*)&target, sizeof(int) );
` passes reference of an int and not reference of reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're taking the address of a reference - this produces the address of the variable `target` refers to. A reference is an alias of the variable it refers to, there's no syntactic indirection anywhere - so any operation performed on the reference affects the referred to variable.

```
int x; 
int & y=x;
```

Using the above, anything you do to `y` will work exactly as if you did it to `x`

Comment: I see.  So basically dereferncing target dereferences b which returns the same thing as target?

Comment: You're not dereferencing, you're taking the address of. Apart from that, *anything* you do to `target` within `ReadInt` will work as if you did it directly to `b`

Comment: The emphasis is on the "alias" nature of references. Think of them as alternative names for variables. If you embrace this view, you won't get confused about things like this.

Comment: Thanks.  That all makes sense.  One more thing that confuses me about this issue.

Why does this not work?
    this->read( (char*)target, sizeof(int) );
target is a reference so it seems to me that it should work.
EDIT: To be clear all I changed here was removing the & before target

Comment: @Daniel: You're casting an int to a pointer - that'll work just as bad as casting `b` to a pointer. `target` is in *every way* simply another name for `b` - you shouldn't care whether it is an `int &` or `int` when you use it - there's **no difference whatsoever** in the code you write to use it.

Comment: I gotcha.  Same misunderstanding both times I'm way slow.
Thanks :)

Comment: If @Erik's answer (and comments) cleared up everything for you, consider accepting it. :)

Answer (score 2):

The code `&target` isn't giving you a reference to a reference, it's giving you the address of the original object that the reference is pointing to. So you've taken an `int*` and converted it to a `char*` (using a C-style cast).

Answer (score 0):

For all intents and purposes, a reference is nothing other than the object that the reference was created from. This includes taking the address of the reference.